# Escape characters from a bash variable

Tags: bash, scripts, sed

I am trying to search-and-replace strings in a configuration template, using bash variables.

Bash variables

```
BACKUP_KEY="ABCDEFG"
BACKUP_ROOT="/var/backup"
```

Configuration template (`template.conf`):

```
GPG_KEY='BACKUP_KEY_ID'
GPG_OPTS="--pinentry-mode loopback"
TARGET='file://BACKUP_ROOT/partA'
SOURCE='/partA'
MAX_AGE=3M
```

Expected outcome:

```
GPG_KEY='ABCDEFG'
GPG_OPTS="--pinentry-mode loopback"
TARGET='file:///var/backup/partA'
SOURCE='/partA'
MAX_AGE=3M
```

This is easy for the first parameter, using `sed`, but the backslash in the second parameter needed to be escaped for `sed`.

```
# What I try
sed "s/BACKUP_KEY/${BACKUP_KEY}/g; s/BACKUP_ROOT/${BACKUP_ROOT}/g" template.conf > ~/.duply/partA/conf
# What this becomes
sed "s/BACKUP_KEY/ABCDEFG/g; s/BACKUP_ROOT//var/backup/g" template.conf > ~/.duply/partA/conf
```

I found the bash extension that would allow adding single-quotes, i.e. `${BACKUP_ROOT@Q}`, but I did not find an option so far to escape the backslash in the `BACKUP_ROOT` parameter.

I wonder if there is any elegant option to achieve that? Note, that I need the un-escaped variables in several other places, so I would prefer *not* to additionally define them with escape backslashes `BACKUP_ROOT_ESC="\\/var\\/backup"`. That would definitly not be elegant ;)

I would also prefer *not* to use a different limiter, because I also have other variables, for example, passwords that may contain other characters accidently matching the search/replace delimiters. So, finding a way to auto-escape the slash (and maybe also the backslash) would be the most reliable option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As a matter of style, you should avoid all caps variable names*

It's not an expansion flag like `Q`, but you could use the generic `${parameter//pattern/string}` with `pattern` set to a literal slash `\/` and `string` set to a literal backslash - literal slash `\\\/`:

```
$ echo "${BACKUP_ROOT}"
/var/backup

$ echo "${BACKUP_ROOT//\//\\\/}"
\/var\/backup

$ echo "TARGET='file://BACKUP_ROOT/partA'" | sed "s/BACKUP_ROOT/${BACKUP_ROOT//\//\\\/}/"
TARGET='file:///var/backup/partA'
```

Comment: Crazy what one can do in the shell :D Thank you very much!